# How can I fix instance of 'class name' printed out Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tostring, instanceof

I'm trying to print forecast.dart, but I'm getting 'instance of WeatherData' printed out. I added `@override String toString()` but no changes.. I'm not quite sure why forecast.dart is not printed out.. please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
String toString();
```

You need to actually add an implementation. `return` the string you want to see when it prints.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `toString`. For example, you could do it like this:

```
@override
String toString() => 'Weather for ${placeName ?? 'unknown'}';
```

Alternatively, you could use https://pub.dev/packages/freezed. It automatically generates useful functions (such as `fromJson`, `toJson`, `toString`) for you. You'll save a lot of time this way.